# Bootstrap DateTimePicker: Space between number columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using DateTimePicker to display a date calendar, which all works well. I have added a light grey background between the dates as seen in the image below; however, I do want to add some padding and border-radius; however, no matter how I try I cannot get it to work.[image]

Inspecting the date element, they have a `day` class which I apply padding on, but it does not work at all.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi perhaps increase the specificity of your css rule (or use !important)?

Comment: I tried to use !important but still does not work...

Answer (score 0):

I probably should have mentioned that the columns are in a table. To solve this out try to apply the following styles on your table as in:

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px 5px;
}
```